# Most intricate and most beautiful structures in mathematics

Tags: big-list, soft-question

In the December 2010 issue of *Scientific American*, an article "A Geometric Theory of
Everything" by A. G. Lisi and J. O. Weatherall states "... what is arguably the most
intricate structure known to mathematics, the exceptional Lie group E8." Elsewhere in the
article it says "... what is perhaps the most beautiful structure in all of
mathematics, the largest simple exceptional Lie group. E8." Are these sensible
statements? What are some other candidates for the most intricate structure and for the
most beautiful structure in all of mathematics? I think the discussion should be confined
to "single objects," and not such general "structures" as modern algebraic geometry.

Question asked by [Richard Stanley](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2807/richard-stanley)

---

Here are the **top candidates** so far:

1) The absolute Galois group of the rationals

2) The natural numbers (and variations)

4) Homotopy groups of spheres

5) The Mandelbrot set

6) The Littlewood Richardson coefficients (representations of $S_n$ etc.)

7) The class of ordinals

8) The monster vertex algebra

9) Classical Hopf fibration

10) Exotic Lie groups

11) The Cantor set

12) The 24 dimensional packing of unit spheres with kissing number 196560 (related to 8).

13) The simplicial symmetric sphere spectrum

14) F_un (whatever it is)

15) The Grothendiek-Teichmuller tower.

16) Riemann's zeta function

17) Schwartz space of functions

And there are a few more...

Comment: With great respect for Richard-and without going so far as to call for it's closure,because it is an interesting question-I think if anyone of lesser stature in the mathematical community had posted this question,there would have numerous calls to close it as too general and subjective.

Comment: The main output of this question will likely be a reinforcement of the ego of each domain/community. Not that good for the unity of mathematics.

Comment: IMO, the statements *are* sensible because they include the words "arguably" and "perhaps".  In other words, I think there is little objective content to them.  With all due respect to the OP, I think this question is the epitome of "subjective and argumentative", and I have voted to close for that reason.  

Comment: Denis is right, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Although perhaps inappropriate for here, since the question apparently has some interest to people, is there a good other place to refer it?

Comment: I am strongly against closing this and similar questions. Is the author famous mathematician or unknown freshman - no difference. "The most intricate" may sound bit provoking, but it is clear that nobody is going to seriously compare different structures, say, E_8 vs. natural numbers, with offensive remarks to opponents (ah, "your Monster group is just a stupid finite object, computer does it better than human being!"), holywars etc.  


Comment: I think the question is really good and deserves its place on MO. This said (and this is in no way in reference to the OP, it is just a general rant) I've noticed that often on MO when someone with no points posts a soft question/big list type of question there is always the same bunch of people who rush to close it and to say basically it's lame. When a professor posts a question virtually of the same order, he gets 80 votes up and congratulations on the "amazing question". I've seen many examples of that and it is this same "police" going to every post and deciding what's good, what's bad.

Comment: @alephomega: it is possible the professors have more experience asking these kinds of questions, and formulate them in a more palatable way? I have seen many questions being closed and then re-opened after the OP rewrote them, though they were asking essentially the same thing, thus proving that how you write things is important (a fact that my students have obvious trouble coming to terms with).

Comment: @alephomega: Bayesian prior

Comment: Since this has already attracted a vote to reopen (at time of typing) I've opened a thread on meta MO ( http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/834/most-intricate-and-most-beautiful-structures-in-mathematics/ ); if you feel the question should be reopened please take the discussion there. Also, please vote this comment up for visibility.

Comment: +1, Yemon: I think we can disagree with each other -- and even complain about each other -- without throwing around terms like "Gestapo".  

Comment: [deleted earlier comment which referred to another earlier comment which has now been deleted]

Comment: it looks like the question "keep it open or close?" provokes much more argumentative discussions, then the initial mathematical question...

Comment: Fedor, please take discussion on opening or closing the question to the meta thread. If you are not already registered on meta, it is easy to do so as far as I recall.

Comment: I have voted to reopen, although I  think there is only one answer, and it has been given below by Steven Landsburg: the monoid $\mathbf N$.

Comment: I don't think this question is argumentative; only the discussion about whether it should "be here" or not is. The answers so far are civil and quite interesting and informative answers are possible. What's the harm in keeping it here?

Comment: I propose to use the tag "short list" rather than the tag "big list". Certainly if the questions will remain closed it will be a short list. But even if it reopened (there is one vote missing for that), since it is about the MOST intricate and MOST beautiful objects in the whole mathematics I suppose it is going to stay a rather short list.

Comment: Gil, as I mention in a comment below, I think this question would be a lot more interesting if it asked for an object that is *both* intricate and beautiful. There are too many choices for things that are only one or the other.

Comment: Deane, OK, let's understand the problem as such! It remind me the question: who are the father and son that contributed most to mathematics. 

Comment: Gil: Is the answer "Riemann and his father"?

Comment: Sheikraisinrollbank: that's the idea of this joke (but I heard it about Gauss). I think it is definitely a big list problem although I expected a short list... 

Comment: I wonder if the "set of mathematicians" can be regarded as a contender. It is intricate and beautiful structure and in some strong sense it is "in mathematics".

Comment: I have deleted a comment by Patrick I-Z.

Comment: Hey Scott, you couldn't do the natural isomorphism ?

Too bad ;-)

Comment: What happened to 3)?

Comment: In my opinion the empty set is a very beautiful thing. Its lack of intricacy is closely connected with its beauty.

Comment: Yet again, I'm happy that people managed to get these nice answers in, despite the haters wanting to close the question.

Comment: @Tom Goodwillie in fact the empty set is included in the above list!

Comment: @16278263789 I completly agree with your comment. This situation is not limited to MO but it is the case in some (not all) scademic or publication carrer

Answer (score 72):

The absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$. It contains the information of all algebraic extensions of the rationals - and is therefore the most important single object of algebraic number theory. Representations of the absolute Galois group are central to many diophantine questions; see for example the Taniyama-Shimura conjecture (aka modularity theorem) which led to a solution of Fermat's last theorem and states in some form that certain Galois representations associated to elliptic curves come from modular forms.

One of the most intricate set of conjectures is dedicated (partly) to the study of representations of the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$: the Langlands program.

Comment: +1. 

And if that's not intricate enough you can upgrade to the conjectural motivic Galois group; the absolute Galois group being the quotient corresponding to varieties of dimension 0. 

Comment: How about the equally conjectural Langlands group ?  But frankly, these are all "derived" from the monoid $\mathbf N$ by some "constructions".

Comment: I would like to know what can I read to get an appreciation for this absolute galois group?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think a good place to start is almost any book on algebraic number theory/class field theory eg. Algebraic Number Theory by Cassels and Fröhlich. It should be noted that such texts mainly consider the abelianizations of absolute Galois groups, which are, while difficult enough, of course much simpler than the full story. 

Comment: Maud: "Fearless Symmetry" by Ash and Gross is a non-technical introduction to the subject.

Comment: How about the absolute Galois group of the field of fractions of the Grothendieck ring of the ordinals? :)

Answer (score 44):

How about the Leech lattice. This is a 24-dimensional packing of unit spheres where each one touches 196560 others. It is the densest 24-dimensional lattice packing (and very likely the densest 24-dimensional sphere packing, although this has not been proved - EDIT: it has been now). It has a remarkable amount of symmetry, and most of the densest sphere packings known in dimensions < 24 are derived from it (and known sphere packings in dimensions > 24 are nowhere near as dense when normalized for the dimension).

Maybe this is already implicitly included in the list, as it is closely related to the monster vertex algebra.

Comment: I would love to 'see' the Leech lattice somehow.

Comment: I took the liberty to update the part about packings.

Comment: @Jarek: thank you.

Answer (score 42):

The (stable or unstable) homotopy groups of spheres are certainly considered intricate and beautiful by topologists.

Here is an interesting (obvious) fact about the stable homotopy groups of spheres that I learned from Vigelik:

In the category of commutative rings (with unit) there is an initial object, $\mathbb{Z}$. This seems to be one reason the integers are important or rather fundamental. But there is something more fundamental! There is a functor from commutative rings to ring spectra, the Eilenberg-MacLane functor. $H\mathbb{Z}$ is no longer initial in this category, the sphere spectrum is! So somehow the stable homotopy groups of spheres are a pretty cool/fundamental ring.

I do not know a lot about the unstable setting, but there is a lot of extra data that it has.

I think that Lennart's point about intricacy and complexity showing up when you start to try to compute the thing sounds like a confusion of what one means by intricate and complex. But it is not, it is not the messiness of the computation that makes it intricate, it is the way of teasing apart the knowledge we do have in meaningful ways that lead me to believe that it is a very intricate object. Especially all the number theory hidden in the chromatic picture, which is part of what Lennart is referring to when he mentions the moduli stack of formal group laws.

**Edit:**
My advisor pointed out another reason that the stable homotopy groups of spheres are cool: $\pi^S_{*}(S^0)=\pi_{*}(B\Sigma_{\infty})$, so the stable homotopy groups of spheres are the homtopy groups of the classifying space of the the category of finite sets and bijections. This is essentially the Barratt-Priddy-Quillen theorem (I am told, I do not know the precise statement). That is pretty cool too! All that information about finite sets sitting there has to be something.

(seems to look fine now, please ignore the bump)

Comment: Could you provide an argument for non-topologists?

Comment: Intricate becomes clear if one looks at any computation. Beautiful because there is so much structure hidden, much of it related to formal groups. 

Comment: Matt, I hope you won't mind my edits.

Comment: @ Deane: is that a bit better?

Comment: Aw, your answer stole the thunder of my answer (sphere spectrum).  

Comment: No it didn't. Your answer is about a model for the sphere spectrum which is beautiful for the reasons you give. I read your answer as "The category of symmetric spectra is beautiful and intricate." In that interpretation, I think there is no stolen thunder. Maybe I misunderstood your answer though.

Comment: @Sean: Alright, I'll let it slide this time.  But don't let it happen again!!!

Comment: But seriously, the category of symmetric spectra is beautiful and intricate!

Comment: Are you sure, you mean $B\Sigma_\infty$? I think, it should be the topological monoid $\coprod B\Sigma_n$ with monoid structure via block sum. 
$B\Sigma_\infty$ has homotopy groups concentrated in degree 1 (if I'm not mistaken), which is no good here. 

Comment: That is my reason for the quotes, and below I mention that by $\Sigma_{\infty}$ i mean the groupoid with objects finite sets and morphisms bijections. Is that not what you describe?

Comment: Sean -- I still think the terminology in the posting is a bit confusing. If you consider a groupoid which is not a group, then why call it a group?

Comment: @LennartMeier While you are (of course) absolutely right, a variant somehow closer to the way presented in the answer is $B\Sigma_\infty^+$, Quillen's plus construction: sort of "minimal distortion" of $B\Sigma_\infty$ to make it simply connected without changing homology. (Btw what is standardly meant by the classifying space of the groupoid of finite sets and bijections would suffer from more or less the same problem - it would not have any nontrivial homotopy above dimension 1.)

Answer (score 35):

The [monster vertex algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_vertex_algebra).

It is (to date) the central object in [monstrous moonshine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine), since its character is the $q$-expansion of the modular $J$-function, its automorphism group is the monster simple group, and the graded trace of any element of the monster is the $q$-expansion of a genus zero modular function.  The construction of this structure (by Frenkel, Lepowsky, and Meurman) involves ascending a hierarchy of objects that are by themselves quite intricate and beautiful.

1. One begins with the [extended binary Golay code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Golay_code) of length 24.  Up to symmetries, it is the unique copy of $\mathbb{F}_2^{12}$ in $\mathbb{F}_2^{24}$, for which any five basis vectors are contained in a unique codeword (i.e., it forms a Steiner $(5,8,24)$ system).  The codewords are separated by Hamming distance at least 8, so even if 3 bits in a code word are changed the error can be corrected.   The automorphism group of the Golay code is the sporadic simple group $M_{24}$ of order 244823040.
2. Using the Golay code to produce coordinates of generators, one constructs the [Leech lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice) $\Lambda$, which is a rather densely packed copy of $\mathbb{Z}^{24}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{24}$.  One can also make the Leech lattice as a subquotient of the even unimodular lattice $I\!I_{25,1}$, which has its own exceptional properties.  Peter Shor mentioned the Leech lattice in another answer, so I'll just note that its automorphism group is a double cover of Conway's sporadic simple group $Co_1$, which has order 4157776806543360000.
3. For any positive definite even lattice $L$, there is a canonical construction of a [vertex operator algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_operator_algebra) graded by that lattice, called the lattice vertex algebra $V_L$.  I think physicists say that it is the algebra of chiral symmetries of a conformal field theory describing a bosonic string propagating in the torus $L \otimes \mathbb{R}/L$ (but I may have mixed up the words).  It has an action of the holomorph of the algebraic torus $L \otimes \mathbb{C}^\times$.
4. The "-1" automorphism of the Leech lattice induces an automorphism $\theta$ of $V_\Lambda$, and there is a unique irreducible $\theta$-twisted module $V_\Lambda(\theta)$ that inherits an action of the centralizer $2^{1+24}.Co_1$ of $\theta$ in the automorphism group of $V_\Lambda$.  The monster vertex algebra is formed by taking the direct sum of fixed points: $V^\natural = (V_\Lambda)^\theta \oplus (V_\Lambda(\theta))^\theta$.

Apparently, the hard part was proving that the monster acts on $V^\natural$ by automorphisms.

There are some additional conjectural reasons for considering it beautiful:

1. In the same paper where it was constructed, it was conjectured to be the unique vertex operator algebra with central charge 24, character equal to the modular $J$ function, and representation category equivalent to $Vect$.  (Naturally, this does not account for higher structure like twisted modules.)
2. [Witten suggested](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.3359) that it is dual to pure 3-dimensional quantum gravity with minimal cosmological constant by AdS/CFT correspondence.

Comment: This one seems promising, but any chance you could elaborate on why the monster vertex algebra is beautiful?

Comment: Dear Deane, I am not sure if the wording of the question: "What are some other candidates for the most intricate structure and for the most beautiful structure in all of mathematics?" insist that the same object is intricate and beautiful.

Comment: Gil, I didn't notice that! It seems to me that the question is more interesting if you demand both!

Answer (score 32):

Since one of the questions is *Are these sensible statements?*, allow me to answer that one with a resounding **NO**, and be on record against the size-ism inherent in the statements of Scientific American. As the largest simple exceptional Lie group, E8 deserves credit for both intricacy and beauty. but the author seems to imply that the size record makes E8 not only more intricate but *also more  beautiful* than the other simple exceptional Lie groups.

Granted I don't know much about Lie groups, but it really bothers me that an aesthetic judgment can be based on size alone. Last I checked, paintings are not judged on their size.

Comment: Have you ever seen *Guernica* in person?  It's breathtaking ;)

Answer (score 32):

The [Mandelbrot Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) is widely viewed as beautiful and intricate, although I can't give a mathematical definition for those.

[image: Mandelbrot Set image]

[image]

The imperfect self-similarities are no accident. Many of the pieces correspond to the behaviors of the critical point $0$ under iteration of $z \to z^2 + c$.To each point in the plane, there is a corresponding Julia set, and the relationship of the point to the Mandelbrot set indicates some of the structure of the Julia set.

Comment: It is a set with a geometrical depiction of great beauty and intricacy, but... how is it a structure?

Comment: It is a set so that each point in the set and its complement can be marked up with an associated Julia set and the behavior of $0$. I don't know what more is needed to call it a structure. If you want a more algebraic structure on top, then look at, for example, homeomorphisms on subsets of the Mandelbrot set from quasiconformal surgeries. 

Comment: Discussion here: http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/10/benot_mandelbrot.html

Comment: I have a question about the Mandelbrod set, which is so naive that I don't dare to ask it as an actual stand-alone question: Are the various ovals (connected components of the interior of the Mandelbrod set) perfect circles? If not, do they have smooth boundary? Are they bounded by algebraic curves?

Comment: @André Henriques: The biggest region is an exact cardiod. The second is an exact circle. At least many of the smaller regions which look circular are not exactly circular: http://linas.org/art-gallery/bud/bud.html

Answer (score 32):

Here an answer in form of a question:

does it strike anyone that many of the candidates for "most intricate and/or beautiful structure in mathematics" proposed here find their natural joint home where they meaningfully relate to each other in... string theory?

- $E_8$ as a GUT group (see the beautiful exposition ([Witten 02](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/GUT#Witten02))), $G_2$ [as a structure group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/M-theory%20on%20G2-manifolds), and in fact the whole tower of [exceptional generalized geometries](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exceptional%20generalized%20geometry) inside [11d SuGra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/11-dimensional%20supergravity);
- the Leech lattice and the monster vertex operator algebra for evident reasons and reasons [already mentioned](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/3d%20quantum%20gravity);
- the [Grothendieck-Teichmüller tower](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck-Teichmueller+tower) for obvious reasons ("hence" also the absolute Galois group..);
- [geometric Langlands correspondence](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+Langlands+correspondence#RelationToSDuality) as but one incarnation of [S-duality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/S-duality);
- [tmf](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tmf), being the target of the [partition function of the heterotic string](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Witten%20genus) (and [tmf0(2)](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tmf0%282%29) as the coefficients for the partition function of the type I superstring; and [conjecturally](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/modular+equivariant+elliptic+cohomology) the whole system of $Tmf(\Gamma)$s for [F-theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/F-theory))

These are just the most evident. One could go on about how the motivic Galois group [also fits in](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motives%20in%20physics) etc., but I don't want to strain it.

What sometimes makes me wonder is that mathematicians have all that appreciation for all these separate intricate and beautiful phenomena that come out of string theory, one by one, including an [impressive list of Fields-awarded work](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string%20theory#FieldMedalWork), but that there is little appreciation that closely similar (just vastly "bigger") to how the Moonshine conjecture qualified as a problem in mathematics, the question "What is string theory?" may be one of the deepest open problems possibly not in phyisics, but in mathematics.

Answer (score 30):

One of the most beautiful structures, in my mind, is the classical Hopf fibration, which allows you to visualize the $3$-sphere $S^3$ as a smooth circle bundle over the $2$-sphere. When you view $S^3$ minus a point as $\mathbb R^3$, one can actually draw very nice pictures of this fibration. It's doubly interesting to me because it involves the isomorphism of $S^2$ with $\mathbb C\mathbb P^1$ from complex analysis.

There are actually 4 such Hopf fibrations (spheres which are total spaces of fibre bundles whose base and fibre are also both spheres):

1) $S^1$ is an $S^0$ bundle over $\mathbb R \mathbb P^1 \cong S^1$.

2) $S^3$ is an $S^1$ bundle over $\mathbb C \mathbb P^1 \cong S^2$.

3) $S^7$ is an $S^3$ bundle over $\mathbb H \mathbb P^1 \cong S^4$, the quaternionic projective line.

4) $S^{15}$ is an $S^7$ bundle over $\mathbb O \mathbb P^1 \cong S^8$, the octonionic projective line.

Comment: In the interest of full disclosure: I copied and pasted some of this from my own answer to another question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44635/sn-to-sm-to-b-bundle-possible/44637#44637

Comment: I agree that these are among the most beautiful structures in geometry and topology, but I'm not sure that they qualify as being "intricate".

Comment: @Deanne: You're correct, they're not as intricate as the Mandlebrot set or the Cantor set, but it's amazing to me that one can fill up all of $\mathbb R^3$ completely with disjoint circles (and one line), any two of which are non-trivially linked. [But I deliberately called them beautiful only, not intricate.]

Comment: I think they also have intricate highly symmetric triangulations. E.g. "Kuhnell's CP^2". They are beautiful and intricate but perhaps not even aiming to be the most beautiful/intricate. (They are quite modest, just 9 vertices.)  

Comment: @Spiro: do you mean disjoint tori? that is the story i recall. Please ignore me if this is dumb. PS thanks for including your example #4

Comment: Dror Bar-Natan has a beautiful animation of the Hopf fibration: http://www.math.toronto.edu/drorbn/Gallery/KnottedObjects/PlanetHopf/

Comment: @Sean: It is both. $\mathbb R^3$ is the union of disjoint circles and a line, any two of which are linked, and one can use this description to also view $\mathbb R^3$ as the disjoint union of tori and a line.

Comment: Thanks, that is really cool. So are they linked like so http://homepages.wmich.edu/~drichter/hopffibration.htm ?

Comment: @Sean: Yup, that is the Hopf fibration. 

Answer (score 29):

The [Turing degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree) are an immensely intricate poset $\mathcal{D}$.  Here are some of their remarkable properites:

1. Every countable poset is embeddable in $\mathcal{D}$.
2. $\mathcal{D}$ contains *minimal* degrees.  (a non-zero degree $\mathbf{m}$ with no degree between $\mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{m}$)
3. For every non-zero degree $\mathbf{d}$, there is a degree that is incomparible with $\mathbf{d}$.
4. $\mathcal{D}$ contains an antichain of size $2^{\aleph_0}$.
5. No infinite strictly increasing chain in $\mathcal{D}$ has a least upper bound.
6. For every degree $\mathbf{d} \geq \mathbf{0}' $, there is a degree $\mathbf{c} < \mathbf{d}$ such that $\mathbf{c}'=\mathbf{d}$.  (Here $\mathbf{c}'$ denotes the set of indices of oracle Turing machines that halt when using $\mathbf{c}$ as an oracle.  Note that one must check that this is well-defined on degrees.)
7. For any two recursively enumerable degrees, there is a recursively enumerable degree strictly between them.
8. Any finite distributive lattice can be embedded in the recursively enumerable degrees.

Comment: @Tony : Nit-picking: 3, 6 should be for non-zero degrees. I would also mention the definability of the map $x\mapsto x'$.

Comment: I know I'm over 4 years late, but shouldn't 6. say that it's so for degrees which are $\geq\mathbf{0}'$? Otherwise a minimal degree serves as a counterexample.

Comment: @Wojowu There is no statute of limitations on comments.  I edited accordingly.  Since this post is community wiki, I think you could have also edited the entry yourself.  Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

The [Littlewood-Richardson coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood-Richardson_rule).  (Or, if one wants a single object, as per the rules of the game: the representation ring of $S_n$ or $GL_n({\bf C})$.  Or the ring of symmetric functions.  Or the cohomology ring of the Grassmannian with the Schubert variety basis.  Etc., etc.)

On the one hand, the Littlewood-Richardson coefficients have fairly simple geometric descriptions (using such combinatorial gadgets as Young tableaux, honeycombs, or puzzles), but on the other hand obey a number of deep recursive properties.  (See for instance [my Notices article](http://www.ams.org/notices/200102/fea-knutson.pdf) with Allen Knutson on one aspect of these coefficients.)  Last, but not least, they are connected to an amazing number of areas of mathematics (see e.g. [Fulton's survey article](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2000-37-03/S0273-0979-00-00865-X/)).

Answer (score 26):

I believe the natural numbers are the most intricate and beautiful structure in all of mathematics.  Particularly insofar as all of the other intricate and beautiful structure we actually work with can be encoded via the natural numbers.

Comment: +1: how not to agree! (But then I'd be tempted to say: *the empty set*! We can describe all natural numbers by simple operations on it, via the von Neumann's ordinal construction) 

Comment: On the other hand, the natural numbers might not be the most intricate object in mathematics..

Comment: Yes, I think this the answer.

Comment: Oh, already closed... I just wanted to add the empty set, because even the natural numbers can be constructed from here...

Comment: While the empty set may be a profound notion, how is it an *intricate* object?

Comment: @Yemon: Interesting <cough> argument.  The issue seems a bit <cough> subjective though...

Comment: The natural numbers are the most intricate because anybody can make any statement, however simple, that will take centuries, even millenia to prove.  And once THAT particular statement does get proved, the 'intricacy' also becomes 'beauty'.  C'mon guys!  Mathematics is about simplifying complexities, not the other way around... :-)

Comment: To try and put across my objection to this answer with a metaphor: is sand intricate because we can make stained glass?

Comment: [deleted some comments of mine which on reflection made more heat than light]

Comment: @Pete: Do you need a glass of water for that cough?

Comment: Also the two most common categorifications belong here, imho: The cat of finite sets and its groupoid coreflection, connecting to combinatorial species, stable homotopy groups of spheres etc... 

Comment: Steven, This is certainly an answer from the book, and probably a nice feeling to nominate the natural numbers...

Comment: Why the empty set in particular?  The empty set is constructed from nothing at all on day zero.  How's it more special than any of the other sets you construct later on the path to natural numbers?


Comment: I don't know; this answer seems a little too cheap and easy somehow. (Deane Yang responded to a deleted answer on the Mandelbrot set, "My objection to an answer like this is that no reasoning is given for the conclusion." The same objection could be made here; it's almost reminds me of an MC saying, "our next awardee is so well-known he needs no introduction".) In summary, the problem with this answer is that I learned *absolutely nothing* from it, and indeed I can't imagine anyone learning anything whatsoever from it. So, -1.  

Answer (score 23):

Let $g$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $3g-3 + n > 0$ Let $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ the moduli stack of genus $g$ nodal curves with $n$ marked points. There are *three* obvious families of maps

forgetting a point

$$\mathcal{M}_{g,n+1} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_{g,n}$$

identifying two marked points on two different curves yielding a new one

$$\mathcal{M}_{g_1,n_1+1} \times \mathcal{M}_{g_2,n_2+1} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_{g_1 + g_2,n_1 + n_2}$$

and identifying two marked points on a single curve yielding a new one with higher genus

$$
\mathcal{M}_{g,n+2} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_{g+1,n}
$$

This system constitutes the so-called Grothendieck-Teichmüller tower. It is indeed intricate and in my opinion, also beautiful. Moreover, it is a conjecture of Grotehndieck that its automorphism group is naturally isomorphic to the absolute Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$, namely $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}|\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Grothendieck's exposition of this in his "Esquisse d'un programme" is quite nice... English: http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/EsquisseEng.pdf French: http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/EsquisseFr.pdf

Answer (score 19):

The class of all ordinals.  The class of cardinals is embedded within it (if AC holds) since one identifies a cardinal with the smallest ordinal such that the set of all smaller ordinals has that cardinality.  ($\aleph_0$ is the cardinality of the set of all finite ordinals, $\aleph_1$ is the cardinality of the set of all countable ordinals, etc.  $\aleph_\omega$ is the cardinality of the set of all ordinals whose cardinality is $\aleph_n$ for some finite $n$. ($\omega$ is the ordinal that gets identified with $\aleph_0$ in the aforementioned identification) $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ is the set of all ordinals of cardinality $\aleph_\omega$, and so on.  $\aleph_\omega$ is the smallest cardinal greater than $\aleph_0$ that is known not to be equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$.)

But if grading is only based on "intricacy", maybe the class of all sets, conventionally denoted "V" because it looks like the letter V (?) might be in first place.  Some people have tried to embed all of mathematics within this thing.

**Later edit:** The "\aleph"s and the "\omega"s are failing to get rendered when I view this thing.  Look at the code and you'll see them.

Comment: I've heard "V" is called that way because of Von Neumann. I haven't seen definite evidence one way or the other.

Comment: I think I've heard that one too.

Comment: I've looked at this from two different browsers and on one of them I do see the mathematical notation.  On the other I see that something is the smallest cardinal greater than 0 that is known not to be equal to 2.  (Of course, that's not what I wrote!)  Except that the "0" has a space before it and is in a subscript position, and the 2 has a space after it before the period.  Before today, math notation in TeX on math overflow was legible.  Something changed.  I've reported the bug on meta.

Comment: This is not even a mathematical object. Next!

Comment: @Harry - in GBN or algebraic set theory...

Comment: Today the math notation is visible.

Comment: @Harry: I suspect that what you meant is either that it's not a _set_ or that it's not one of the things referred to in the first-order language of set theory.  Or something like that.  And I have to suspect that David Roberts had the same thing in mind.  But I think the idea that that is the essence of mathematical-objecthood is debatable.

Comment: @Harry: it is without question a mathematical object! Conway’s manifesto for the “Mathematicians’ Liberation Movement” is worth reading in this connection — the liberation being from foundational constraints. It can be read as dismissive of questions of foundations — and I’d strongly disagree with that; I work largely with foundational structures, I think they can be very illuminating, and I care passionately about them. [cont’d]

Comment: But the point I do agree with, and have never seen a serious argument against, is that if mathematicians are working with something, and working with it mathematically, *then it is mathematics* — and if it doesn’t quite fit into a particular foundation, this is a problem with the foundation, not the mathematics.  If it looks like a mathematical object, smells like a mathematical object, has theorems about it like a mathematical object, then it’s a mathematical object.

Answer (score 19):

Ok, I'll throw my hat in the ring: I like the classical Cantor set.

Not only does it demonstrate the complexity that relatively simple subsets of the real line have,  it illustrates an important property of measures on the real line - namely, that measurability has nothing to do with cardinality of the set (i.e. this is an uncountable set with measure zero!)

It also gives an example of a completely disconnected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that literally has no components - it contains no open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ in its power set.

There are many, many more observations one can make about the Cantor set, but I think the obvious ones make my point very nicely. When I teach real analysis, this is an example I think I'll be using a great deal to illustrate properties of the real line.

Comment: I like the classics,ok? 

Comment: OK.   $           $

Comment: Perhaps it would be more accurate to say that the Cantor set has many components, since its connected components are its points.

Comment: Ok,fair enough,Scott. But let's face it-we don't normally consider singletons components of infinite topological spaces. But again,it further shows the sheer counterintuitivity of the properties of the Cantor set. It's why it's such a potent counterexample to how we "expect" subsets of the real line to behave.  

Comment: I think that the _fat_ Cantor set is the one that gives the surprising result.  It is a bounded nowhere-dense set with positive measure.

Comment: Andrew, I disagree.  Both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are infinite topological spaces that, under the subspace topologies inherited from $\mathbb{R}$, are made out of singleton components.  Both spaces are used quite frequently in mathematics.

Comment: Fair enough-I stand corrected.

Comment: Another slightly less artificial example (I don't think the discrete topology of $\mathbb{Z}$ illuminates the structure of the integers a great deal) would be pro-finite groups, $p$-adic numbers, etc. Their topology is extremely important and they are totally disconnected.

Comment: As it happens, profinite groups like the $p$-adic integers have a remarkable tendency to be homeomorphic to the Cantor set.  One might even add this to the entry in support of the cause.

Answer (score 18):

This has been forgotten so far: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

Comment: I have just rolled back an edit whose author took it upon himself to expound on universality of the zeta function. While interesting, I see no indication that this is what the OP @JohannesEbert intended

Answer (score 17):

$\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$.

It can also be thought as the set of prime numbers. I don't know if it can really be considered "intricate"...

Comment: as an aside I saw a 'simple question', what does Spec(Z) look like with the etale topology?, and the response given was that answering that question is essentially the point of arithmetic geometry. so perhaps not so simple

Answer (score 10):

In my view it is difficult to come up with an alternative to any of the exotic Lie groups, which are unquestionably quite intricate but are also beautiful because they express the properties of certain geometric spaces using both fundamental algebra (i.e., groups) and geometric structures of their own (i.e., Riemannian geometry). I don't know $E_8$ particularly well, but I still have vivid memories of Robert Bryant's lectures describing the structure of $G_2$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on $G_2$ then? I don't know much about lie groups, but would love to hear about the geometry.

Comment: @Sean: post it as a question, and I will be happy to give a fairly detailed answer.


Comment: If Sean doesn't do this soon, I will. My vague recollection is that you look at the 7-dimensional space of imaginary octonions. Since multiplication is not associative, there is a naturally defined 3-form that expresses the non-associativity, and $G_2$ arises as the group that preserves the 3-form. The first person to try to explain the octions to me was Calabi, when I was still an undergraduate. Then Bryant explained it again, right after he showed that $G_2$ can be the holonomy group of a non-symmetric Riemannian metric.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49357/g-2-and-geometry

Answer (score 10):

The outer automorphisms of the group $S_6$ of all permutations of a set of six objects.

$6$ is the only number for which $S_n$ has any outer automorphisms.

The group inner automorphisms of $S_6$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in the group of all automorphisms of $S_6$, and --- here's a (probably) unexpected fact: It's one of exactly three subgroups of index $2$, no two of which are isomorphic to each other.

Comment: And this is nicely explained in Rotman's book on group theory.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff : Does Rotman explain that the group of all automorphisms of $S_6$ has exactly three subgroups of index $2$? $\qquad$

Comment: Hm, I don't think so. Not at least in the edition I have.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff : Nonetheless I'll probably look at Rotman. $\qquad$

Answer (score 10):

The Surreal numbers as constructed by Conway.

They contain a copy of many objects already on the list ($\mathbb{N},O_n$) and so surpass them in complexity, and they are recursively defined from the empty set using $O_n$ length recursions which is incredibly beautiful.

I would also propose the absolute Galois group of the field of fractions of the Grothendieck ring of the ordinals, however I have very little understanding of this object (nor does anyone else to my knowledge).

Comment: ${\bf R}^3$ contains a copy of many objects already on the list – does that mean it surpasses them in complexity?

Comment: @GerryMyerson If we allow definitions of all order over $\mathbb{R}^3$ then I'd say yes; if we stick to first order definitions it may be simpler, since RCF is complete but PA isn't.

Comment: I don't know what any of that means. But I note that user Ultradark has just posted (a model of) ${\bf R}^3$ as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson First order definitions, quantifying over individual members, allow these structures to be perceived and understood in a relatively simple manner. If you allow second or higher order quantification over the objects in play, I would argue that the surreals surmount any previously conceived totally ordered field in complexity.

Answer (score 9):

I have voted for ${\mathbb N}$; but let me nevertheless propose an object living in the analytical realm, namely the Schwartz space ${\cal S}$ of infinitely differentiable functions $f:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb C}$ that for $|x|\to\infty$ together with their derivatives go to zero faster than any power $1/|x|^n$. The "intricateness" of this space stems from the many operations you can perform in it and from the fact that these operations are intertwined with each other in miraculous ways. $$ $$  Responding to a comment: You have (a) ordinary multiplication and convolution, (b) "multiplication" with arbitrary polynomials $p(x)$ and operations $p(D)$, (c) multiplication with functions of the form $x\mapsto e^{iax}$ and the translation operator $T_a: f(\cdot)\mapsto f(\cdot-a)$ and (d) scaling of the variable $x$ resp. $\xi$. The Fourier transform $\Phi$ interchanges in each of these three cases the respective operations; and at heart of it all is Gauss' normal distribution $x\mapsto {1\over \sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{-x^2/2} dx$ which stays fixed under $\Phi$. And, last not least, there is a scalar product which is preserved by $\Phi$.

Comment: I actually discussed this space with a friend a few months ago. I thought geometrically,this is the space of sequences of rotations in the complex plane and thier subsequences such that the rotations have no nonempty intersection with each other-is this correct?  

Comment: More detail would make a better case. Which transformations? (Fourier transform is one, but which others do you have in mind?)

Answer (score 8):

Another one: [Chaitin's Omega constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin's_constant).

Original answer by: **[none](https://mathoverflow.net/users/11575/none)**

Comment: Why did this get such a low rating? If one knew the Omega constant, then one could solve the halting problem. Moreover, it has a simple, natural definition. 

Comment: It looks like the person who wrote this answer couldn't be bothered to write a sentence or two of explanation or justification.  Anyone with suitable expertise and at least 100 points is welcome to add to it.

Answer (score 8):

I heard good things about [F_un](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/index.php/looking-for-f_un.html)!

Comment: Are you trying to prove the point you made in the meta thread?

Comment: this link works http://cage.ugent.be/~kthas/Fun/index.php/f_un-and-group-representations.html

Answer (score 8):

The generalized cohomology theory known under the name [Topological modular forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_modular_forms):

Here's a picture of the graded ring $\mathit{tmf}\;^*(pt)$:
http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~henri105/PDF/TmfRing.pdf

And here's the spectral sequence used to compute it:
http://math.mit.edu/conferences/talbot/2007/tmfproc/henriques-tmfSS.pdf
Its $E_2$ page is $Ext_{A(2)}(\mathbb F_2,\mathbb F_2)$, where $A(2)$ is this beast:
 http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~henri105/PDF/A2.pdf

Here's another spectral sequence, that computes the closely related graded ring $\mathit{Tmf}\;^*(pt)$:
http://math.mit.edu/conferences/talbot/2007/tmfproc/EllipticSpectralSequence.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this wouldn't be my first choice, but I still think it's worth being on the list: [**Gödel's constructible universe**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe) $L$.

I would argue that it is *intricate* because it can serve as a model for "all of mathematics" (i.e., ZFC), furthermore answering many combinatorial questions left open by ZFC alone.  Even though most(?) set theorists will probably argue that it is not "the" true model giving the right answer to these questions, it is still undoubtedly a rich and complex structure, moreover one in which the axiom of choice and the continuum hypothesis are not only true but "explained".

But it is also *beautiful* because of its connections with higher computability theory (e.g., the sets of integers constructed at the level $\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}}$ of the constructible hierarchy, where $\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}}$ is the smallest nonrecursive ordinal, are exactly the hyperarithmetical sets, i.e., the (lightface) $\Delta^1_1$ sets of the analytic hierarchy), and, in a related manner, because of Jensen's results on the "fine structure" of $L$.  In a very intuitive way, I'd say that $L$ consists of sets that are ultimately "computable" (iterating the Turing jump as far as it can be), a perfectly regular construction that prohibits any randomness.

So even if set theorists are unhappy with $L$ because it forbids really large cardinals, and even if they try to construct something better (the core model), I argue that Gödel's original $L$ is still something immensely intricate and beautiful.

Answer (score 5):

I like the hyperbolic plane where Escher's "circle limits" live.

In the hyperbolic plane you can turn your car (i.e. constant aceleration perpendicular to the constant speed) and not manage to close its trajectory (there are equidistant curves and horocycles).

Also, the symmetry group of the tiling by right angled hexagons contains all but a finite number of closed surface groups.  So you can build almost all closed surfaces gluing these hexagons.

People in the hyperbolic plane wont agree on the angle between two stars (i.e. boundary points)  but if you average the measurements of other people around you the result will agree with your own measurement (hence everyone thinks they are right).

The modular group (and its congruence subgroups) are important in number theory (which I know next to nothing about) and also in complex analysis (where, for example, the congruence subgroup $\Gamma(2)$ is the covering group of the plane minus two points and allows one to prove that if an entire function omits two values in its image it must be constant).

The list could go on (the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, Brownian motion escapes with positive speed to infinity, Anosov property the geodesic flow, quasi-geodesics are at bounded distance from geodesics, the area of a convex hull is bounded by a constant times the number of points, the strong isoperimetric inequality holds i.e. perimeter is greater then volume for all sets, etc, ...).

Comment: If I had not found this answer, I would have posted a similar one myself. Many of the other answers seem to equate "beauty" with "complexity", whereas this one instead equates "beauty" with "simplicity", which is much more to my own taste.

Answer (score 4):

The relationship between the discrete order and the multiplication on the natural numbers leads to, among other things, the study of gaps between primes.  I would nominate a class of structures S(n), which are the sets of integers relatively prime to the nth primorial (p_1p_2...p_n) as a collection worthy of the labels beautiful and intricate.  The symmetry and self-similar nature appeal to many, and while the construction is simple, there are many simple facts remaining to be established about the S(n).  For one, the largest gap between consecutive members of S(n) seems to be unknown.  (Cf [Erik Westzynthius's cool upper bound argument: update?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37679/erik-westzynthiuss-cool-upper-bound-argument-update) for a weak upper bound; I hope to post an improvement soon.)

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.12.13

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's the most beautiful or the most intricate, but I certainly think the random graph $G(n,p)$ deserves consideration, if only for philosophical reasons.

Comment: What philosophical reasons?

Comment: I would say the Erdős–Renyi/Rado graph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph rather than this, if you're looking for something from graph theory. This occurs as the Fraïssé limit of the category of finite graphs and embeddings http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/11/fraisse_limits.html

Comment: David: isn't that graph also known as "the" random graph on a countably infinite vertex set?

Comment: Gil:  For the reason that it can easily demonstrate the existence of a graph with a beautiful and intricate structure without explicitly exhibiting it.  Although you could argue that we may as well say that a coin flip is is an intricate and beautiful structure.  Also, it should maybe be disqualified by your "single object" specification.

Answer (score 4):

How about $\mathbb{R}^n$? I hope people don't consider this example too simplistic. After all, the structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$ gives rise to all of the theory of topological and differentiable manifolds. Specific important highlights include the theory of "algebraic" equations (inverse and implicit function theorems) and the local theory of differential equations (jets, forms, integral submanifolds).

Comment: You should try to repeat Lisi's publicity stunt with $E_8$ replaced by $\mathbb{R}^n$ :-)

Answer (score 4):

Hard to pin down the object I find the most intricate and beautiful mathematical structure, but in my opinion this structure has yet to emerge from the growing body of our knowledge. I believe a structure mathematicians are gradually understanding is manifesting itself in various areas of algebra, number theory, analysis, probability theory, theoretical physics, geometry, topology, set theory and several others, and one might thus say that the most intricate and beautiful structure in mathematics is mathematics itself. More precisely it is some unknown object that all mathematicians study from different sides, angles and perspectives without yet knowing the name for the thing that their discoveries actually have in common. Some evidence to this is given by repeated patterns occurring in several answers here, as well as by some striking instances of partial unification of mathematical concepts, such as (to name very few) Connes' noncommutative geometry, Arakelov theory, Segal's modular functors, topos theory and homotopy type theory.

Answer (score 4):

Many believe (me too!) that finite fields are among the most beautiful mathematical objects (not to mention ***important***).

Answer (score 4):

[Schramm-Loewner evolution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schramm%E2%80%93Loewner_evolution?wprov=sfti1) This is a stochastic differential equation which models the scaling limit of many
stochastic planar processes.

Answer (score 4):

I really like the Collatz conjecture graph ($3n+1$ problem), the graph showing the evolution of natural numbers under the rule:  If $x$ is even, divide by 2; if $x$ is odd, multiply by 3 and add 1.  Here's the graph with $100,000$ nodes:

[image: Collatz graph]

Answer (score 3):

What about the complex numbers, from the way all the theorems of complex analysis fit together so well.

Also: NGB set theory (I mean the formal object Th NBG, not the general informal topic): finitely axiomatizable through an intricate argument, and proves just about everything in mathematics.

Comment: NBG set theory  a.) is not a mathematical object and b.) is conservative over ZFC.  If anything, all that NBG lets you do is write down certain statements a different way (i.e. "For every set $A$" becomes "For all $A \in Sets$".

Comment: @Harry: what on earth do you mean by “it’s not a mathematical object”?  Firstly, in the formal sense, it is, in any reasonable foundation: there is a *set* (yes, a set) which “is” the theory NBG.  But secondly — per the comment I’m about to make on the “ordinals” answer — that’s not relevant: it’s something studied by mathematicians, mathematically; so it’s a mathematical object.

Comment: @Harry: There are statements that you can write in NBG but not in ZFC.  Sometimes it's very convenient to be able to quantify over proper classes; circumlocutions that refer only to sets are not always available, and even when they are, they can be rather cumbersome.

Comment: @HarryGindi You enjoy making grand statements with no justification even when pressed?  You'd do well in religion, it's bad mathematical practice though.

Comment: @AlecRhea Thank you for your enlightening riposte to my eight year old comment (made during my second year as an undergrad).

Comment: @HarryGindi Fair enough, my apologies for not looking at timestamps.  It did provoke some ire in me haha.

Comment: @AlecRhea No worries. I was told at the time that I was quite abrasive and arrogant.

Answer (score 3):

The rotational symmetries within Young's lattice, discovered at the beginning  of the 21st century by Ruedi Suter.  I think the bilateral symmetry has been known many decades, but rotational symmetries were not, and they seem quite surprising.

The Wikipedia link below clearly explains the idea.  The first link is Suter's paper.

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669801905414

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_lattice#Dihedral_symmetry

Answer (score 3):

This is a less-known example. Consider the semigroup
$$
A_0 = \big\{ \big[\begin{smallmatrix} 0&0\\0&0 \end{smallmatrix}\big], \big[\begin{smallmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{smallmatrix}\big], \big[\begin{smallmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{smallmatrix}\big], \big[\begin{smallmatrix} 0&1\\0&1 \end{smallmatrix}\big] \big\}
$$
under usual matrix multiplication. The variety $\mathrm{var}A_0$ generated by $A_0$ is *finitely universal* in the sense that the lattice of subvarieties of $\mathrm{var}A_0$ embeds all finite lattices. The semigroup $A_0$ is a minimal example since the variety generated by any semigroup of order three or less is not finitely universal.

Answer (score 3):

Brownian walk (or Wiener process, to conform to "single object" stipulation).

Answer (score 3):

How about [true arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_arithmetic). True arithmetic is the set of first order statements that $\mathbb N$ satisfies with its usual operations.

One cool thing you can do is construct non-standard models of TA. These will share all first order properties with $\mathbb N$, but could be widely different. This is pretty crazy, considering that they since first-order induction is a property of $\mathbb N$, it is also a property of these models, even though second-order induction fails. The similarities are great enough that you can even encode the same objects for the most part, leading to infinite structures that act like finite ones. For example, you can have infinite turing machines.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Stone-Cech compactification has a  highly and  deeply complexity.

Comment: See my comment to Daniel Geisler's answer.

Comment: I agree with Deane's comment, even though I think a case can be made for $\beta \mathbb N$. (The poster doesn't say what space he is taking the Stone-Cech compactification of, mind you.)

Answer (score 2):

I want to mention the small category $\bf{\Delta}$, where its objects are $[n]$ for a natural number $n$ and its morphism are all maps preserve orders.

I've been told $\bf{\Delta}$ is magic for a long time. Topologists use it to say what a space (simplicial set) is, and algebraic-geometors also use it. We even need it to define the higher categories.

I'm still in learning about this category, and I wish I could know some deep reason why it works so well.

Answer (score -3):

The Selberg class, which is conjectured to contain all L-functions of arithmetic interest. It is closed under multiplication, and is a way to formalize the common properties of L-functions for which we believe the analogue of the Riemann hypothesis holds. Many still open conjectures address its structure, like the degree conjecture, that states an invariant of an element of this class called the degree is always an integer, or Selberg's orthonormality conjecture, that says the set of primitive (meaning irreducible) elements form in some sense an orthormal system, suggesting connections with other parts of math such as Hilbert spaces, representation theory, Galois theory...I fell in love with that class many years ago and can't get my eyes off of it !

Answer (score -8):

Shelah's Body of Work. Considering that [this](http://shelah.logic.at/shelah_a.dvi) list of references is over 100 pages long, I think this a contender.

Comment: No offence, Michael, but you seem to be interpreting the original question rather creatively with this answer.

Comment: @Choi  Indeed, but aren't the best answers creative? If I had said, L, L(A), L[A], the cumulative hierarchy V, the collection of P-names generated by a partial order, or mentioned the PO constructed by essentially 'weaving' together every CCC PO in a ground model to produce a model of MA+'not CH', they would not have elicited the same feelings of respect and amazement, I get when I consider such objects. So I opted for something I could share, which everyone could appreciate, which demands the same sense of respect and amazement. 

Comment: @Blackmon: "aren't the best answers creative" - it depends on your question, doesn't it? As you may see from some of my previous comment s on some of the answers here, I don't find them particularly good. Moreover, although no one else seems to have mentioned things I find kewl, I haven't taken the opportunity to put "the publication record of the late N. J. Kalton" as an answer...

Comment: @Choi Well why haven't you?

Comment: @Blackmon: Because I don't think this is a productive MO question, from the point of view of light rather than heat. I also think "the publication record of the late N. J. Kalton" would be a *poor* answer to the question; and I am not a fan of several other answers to this question. It doesn't help that the title of this question is not quite the same as what the question seems to actually ask for...

Comment: Out of interest, since I see that on other questions you seem happy to use first names, is there some reason you're not doing so here?

Comment: @Choi I agree, this question is nothing more than a place to vent about how "awesome you're field is." I made the choice not to do this, and just posted something everyone should be able to appreciate. With that being said, I think this particular question should be closed, for the reasons highlighted in the comments to the original question.

Comment: @Choi my previous comment was a bit late, what do you mean about using your last name? I'm just trying to be respectful.  

Comment: Oh, I see. Cultural crossed-wires then; my bad